# Splash screen & login dialog box doesn't stick together

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am working on Eclipse RCP application in which I load the splash screen first and then login which asks for credentials and then my main application. But here what problem occurs is "Splash screen & login dialog box don't stick together" like Eclipse's "Splash screen and workspace launcher" when we open Eclipse. Why do I need such mechanism because if I use "Alt"+"Tab" then any of windows get hidden behind current thread so sometime it's very hard to find where is my login box or splash screen.

Answer (score 3):

To behave like the Eclipse splash screen and workspace launcher you need to use the standard Eclipse splash screen mechanism and write your own `IApplication`.

In the `IApplication` `start` method do something like:

```java
@Override
public Object start(IApplicationContext appContext) throws Exception {
    Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();

    try {
        // look and see if there's a splash shell we can parent off of
        Shell shell = WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(display);
        if (shell != null) {
            shell.setText("Login window title");
            shell.setImages(Window.getDefaultImages());
        }

        new LoginDialog(shell);  // Use splash shell as the parent shell

        // TODO call PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench in the usual way
    } 
    finally {
        if (display != null) {
            display.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is my current code:

public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception 
 {
  Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
  try 
  {
   //Platform.endSplash(); 
   
   Shell shell = new Shell(display);
   LoginDialog l1 =new LoginDialog(shell, SWT.NONE);
   l1.open();
   
   return null;
  
  } 
  finally 
  {
   display.dispose();
  }
 }

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's done by changing "Shell shell = WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(display);" line.

Comment: My Eclipse E4 RCP application doesn't reset perspective once i make the product file.  Could you please tell me how to reset it ?

Comment: If you have a new question please ask a Question